# Is this sentence grammatically correct? "To confirm that they gave me the wrong item I checked the box that I have already thrown in the trash."

Tags: grammar

I sent a report yesterday about the wrong item that I received online and now I'm kinda anxious about my grammar. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "...that I _had_ already thrown..." You threw it away before you retrieved it in order to check it.

Comment: @KateBunting unless the OP wants to note that they've thrown the box out by the time of writing the report, in which case *have* seems fine to me (if a little surprising without context). Either way, no need to be particularly anxious, it's a little ungrammatical if OP did indeed mean *had*, but probably not in a way that matters.

Comment: I think you are trying to say that there was a check-box that you marked, to say that you had disposed of the item.  Please give us much more detail about what actually happened. Did you check a box on a form, or did you throw a box in the trash? Your sentence is very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the box that's being checked is a literal, physical box. Your original sentence with only grammar correction:

> To confirm that they gave me the wrong item I checked the box that I had already thrown in the trash.

Also consider this more natural and less ambiguous (because of the multiple meanings of "checked") version:

> I confirmed they had sent me the wrong item by inspecting the delivery box, which I had already thrown away.